# onKeyUp Texftield Auto Generate. HTML/JAVA

Tags: java, javascript, html, textfield

I have a code which enabled the user to enter a Value in the first TextBox and I wanted it to populate the same value in the other TextFields with the same ID. (There are 9 Textfields in a column which have same ID)

Here is my code, but the problem is the value ONLY gets populated in the first inbox (TextF1) and nothing happens to the other 8. Does anyone see the issue here

```
<form >
<input type='text' id='VarField' onKeyUp="document.getElementById('VarField1').value=this.value"  value='' size="10">

<input type='text' name='TextF1' id='VarField1' value='' size="10">
<input type='text' name='TextF2' id='VarField1' value='' size="10">
<input type='text' name='TextF3' id='VarField1' value='' size="10">
.
.
.
<input type='text' name='TextF8' id='VarField1' value='' size="10">
<input type='text' name='TextF9' id='VarField1' value='' size="10">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's bad practice to have more than one tag with the same ID - because of this, the `getElementById` method only accesses the first tag with that ID.  Instead, give each input the same class, select all of them, and iterate through them.

So your code would look something like this (I separated the function from the onKeyUp event to make it easier to see):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function writeText()
    {
        var textFields = document.getElementsByClassName("VarField1");
        for(i = 0; i < textFields.length; i++)
        {
            textFields[i].value = document.getElementById("VarField").value;
        }
    }
</script>

<form >
    <input type='text' id='VarField' onKeyUp="writeText()"  value='' size="10">

    <input type='text' name='TextF1' class='VarField1' value='' size="10">
    <input type='text' name='TextF2' class='VarField1' value='' size="10">
    <input type='text' name='TextF3' class='VarField1' value='' size="10">
    <input type='text' name='TextF8' class='VarField1' value='' size="10">
    <input type='text' name='TextF9' class='VarField1' value='' size="10">
</form>
```

Note that you must iterate through in this way - although it's tempting to use a foreach (for ... in) loop, that will not work for the NodeList that `getElementsByClassName` returns.

Comment: Thank you very, very much. Solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

HTML Elements' ID's are supposed to be unique. By that I mean that only one element should have the ID VarField1.

You could instead try giving each element the same class of VarField1. Then you could use a for-each loop to give each element the proper value. That would look like this:

```
function assignValue( textValue )
{
    for ( textBox in document.getElementsByClassName("VarField1") )
    {
        textBox.value = textValue;
    }
}
```

You onKeyUp attribute would just cal the assignVale() function with the value of the textbox.

`onKeyUp="assignValue(this.value)"`

Answer (score 0):

The issue, I believe, is that you can't have more than one control/element on a page with the same ID.  Try giving them distinct IDs (e.g. `Varfield2`, `Varfield2`, etc.).  That should resolve the problem.